# Can not verify encrypted private key

Tags: java, encryption, openssl, rsa

I have the context below:

I use `openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -sha256 -days 365 -nodes` to generate key and cert files.

Then I use `openssl pkcs8 -in key.pem -out key-encrypted.pem -topk8` to encrypt my private key.

The code works with `key.pem` and `cert.pem`, but has a problem with `key-encrypted.pem` and `cert.pem`.

When it goes to this line to generate private key, it shows an error that `java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : DerValue.getBigIntegerInternal, not expected 48`.

I load my cert file and create the X509Certificate object as below:

```
byte[] certData = Files.readAllBytes(certPath);
InputStream st = new ByteArrayInputStream(certData)
CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
certificate = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(st);
```

Then I load my private key file as below:

```
List<String> keys = Files.readAllLines(keyPath);
//I have removed the first and last line of the key content:
//-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- and -----END PRIVATE KEY----- lines
String key = String.join("", keys);

//Parse it into PKCS8
byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(key);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec ks = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(decoded);

//Now I use kf to generate private key
PrivateKey pk = kf.generatePrivate(ks);

//Then I use the following code to verify
Signature s = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
s.initSign(pk);

byte[] sign = s.sign();
s.initVerify(certificate.getPublicKey());
s.verify(sign);
```

Comment: Not sure why you would recreate the certificate; the private key values remain the same, if it is encrypted or not.

Comment: You are right, @MaartenBodewes. I have rechecked it, and those two certificates remain the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newer [*openssl-pkcs8*](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.2/man1/openssl-pkcs8.html) versions use PKCS#5 v2.0/PBES2 by default, more specifically *aes256* with PBKDF2 and *hmacWithSHA256* (as of v1.1.0 in 2016, s. comment).
While `EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo` suggested in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77721013/can-not-verify-encrypted-private-key/77721927#77721927) supports PBES2 algorithms in Java versions as of 19 (tested for 19-21) this is not the case for older Java versions such as Java 8 or even Java 18 and results in exceptions (which vary depending on the Java version, e.g. *IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = 48)* with Java 8 or *NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBES2 SecretKeyFactory not available* with Java 18).

In the case of a Java version for which `EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo` does not support PBES2 algorithms `org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo` is an option, which also supports PBES2 algorithms:

```java
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMKeyConverter;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.InputDecryptorProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo;
...
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
// Load DER encoded encrypted key
byte[] encryptedPkcs8Der = Base64.decodeBase64(key);
PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo pkcs8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo = new PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(encryptedPkcs8Der);
// Decrypt encrypted key
JcaPEMKeyConverter jcaPEMKeyConverter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter();
InputDecryptorProvider inputDecryptorProvider = new JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder().build("<your password>".toCharArray());
PrivateKeyInfo privateKeyInfo = pkcs8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.decryptPrivateKeyInfo(inputDecryptorProvider);
// Import decrypted key
PrivateKey privateKey = jcaPEMKeyConverter.getPrivateKey(privateKeyInfo);
...
Signature s = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
s.initSign(privateKey);
...
```

Comment: To be clear, although you link to the most recent doc version, `openssl pkcs8 -topk8` has defaulted to PBES2/hmacSHA256/AES256CBC since 1.1.0 in 2016.

Comment: It almost worked in my case. We need to decrypt the private key for verification. I changed this line of code to: PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo pkcs8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo = new PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(encryptedPkcs8Der);
And it works.

Comment: Okay, found the change in 19 (and up); see update at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66286457/load-an-encrypted-pcks8-pem-private-key-in-java

Answer (score 1):

The `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` only supports the *inner* PKCS#8 structure. Encrypted PKCS#8 is not supported directly by this class. However, there is [EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.html) which does.

You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3985508/589259) on how to use the class. Note that nowadays it should use PBES2 (i.e. PBKDF2 + encryption) for the key derivation, so that should be OK.

Comment: Another, deleted answer indicated the use of `PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo` found in Bouncy Castle which could be an option if the Java runtime doesn't like the PKCS#8 encrypted private key. Unfortunately my programming environment is not up and running at the time of speaking. If it were undeleted I would happily vote it up.

Comment: No, just calling `SecretKeyFactory.getInstance` and `Cipher.getInstance` on the OID for PBES2 doesn't work; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66286457/load-an-encrypted-pcks8-pem-private-key-in-java . (It did work on PKCS5.PBES1 and PKCS12PBE schemes where one OID encoded the whole scheme -- pbeWith{kdf}and{symmetric} -- as long as your Java provider(s) implemented that scheme.)

Comment: Partial retraction: it DOES work in j19 up as per other answer; see update.