Java: sign data with OpenSSL-generated RSA key
I have generated a password-protected RSA private key using OpenSSL. In Node.js, I can successfully use this key to sign some data:
import * as crypto from 'node:crypto';
...
const sign = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256');
sign.update(data);
return sign.sign({key: signKey, passphrase: signPassphrase}, "base64");

I'd like to do the same in Java, but I'm failing to properly read the same private key. I've tried the following code (based on some other StackOverflow articles):
        
        private PrivateKey createKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
            var pkcs8KeySpec = passPhrase==null 
                    ? new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKey)
                    : decryptEncodedKeySpec();
            return KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);
        }

        private PKCS8EncodedKeySpec decryptEncodedKeySpec() throws Exception{
            EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encryptPKInfo = new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(privateKey);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(encryptPKInfo.getAlgName());
            PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase);
            SecretKeyFactory secFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(encryptPKInfo.getAlgName());
            Key pbeKey = secFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
            AlgorithmParameters algParams = encryptPKInfo.getAlgParameters();
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, algParams);
            return encryptPKInfo.getKeySpec(cipher);
        }

The code above results in the following exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: PBE parameter parsing error: expecting the object identifier for AES cipher
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.PBES2Parameters.parseES(PBES2Parameters.java:334)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.PBES2Parameters.engineInit(PBES2Parameters.java:238)
    at java.base/java.security.AlgorithmParameters.init(AlgorithmParameters.java:311)
    at java.base/sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.decodeParams(AlgorithmId.java:147)
    at java.base/sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.<init>(AlgorithmId.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.parse(AlgorithmId.java:435)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.<init>(EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.java:101)
    at SignatureHelper.decryptEncodedKeySpec(SignatureHelper.java:207)

Following is the ASN1 info for my private key (empty values and hex dumps removed):
    6:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :PBES2
   21:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :PBKDF2
   50:d=6  hl=2 l=   8 prim: OBJECT            :hmacWithSHA256
   64:d=4  hl=2 l=   8 prim: OBJECT            :des-ede3-cbc

Again based on other StackOverflow articles, I think the algorithm mentioned in the last line (des-ede3-cbc) is related to this issue, but despite many Google/StackOverflow searches, I haven't found any way to fix this.
If I remove the passphrase from my private key (using openssl rsa -in key.pem), the code above can successfully read the key and use it for signing.
Sample encrypted private key (passphrase: test) that results in the Java code throwing an exception, generated using openssl genpkey -algorithm rsa -out test.key -des-ede3-cbc with OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022:
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----

Any ideas/suggestions?

Post the exact OpenSSL statement used to generate the key and the OpenSSL version, and/or a non-productive sample key and password.

Unfortunately, I don't recall the exact OpenSSL statement used to generate the key. Ideally, that shouldn't matter either, as I'd like the Java code to work with arbitrary RSA keys.
Anyway, I'm using OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022, just used the following command to generate a sample private key: openssl genpkey -algorithm rsa -out test.key -des-ede3-cbc, exposing the same exception.

Thanks for the replies, unfortunately still no luck: openssl genpkey -algorithm rsa -out test.key -aes256 results in java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting PBES2 on Cipher.getInstance(encryptPKInfo.getAlgName());

(reninjad) 'Standard' (Oracle/OpenJDK) Java crypto can only handle PBES2 encryption that uses AES-128-CBC or AES-256-CBC. Generate your key with openssl genpkey ... -aes128 or ... -aes256, or convert an existing one with openssl pkey -in old -out new {-aes128|-aes256} . And to use EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.algName() as you do, make sure to use Java 19 up (not 11.0.18, my notes were wrong), else see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66286457/load-an-encrypted-pcks8-pem-private-key-in-java .

If BouncyCastle is an option, the posted key can easily be imported with it, see online on jdoodle https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/10Vl.

We're using Java 17 (can't upgrade to later version yet), so I guess this is causing the PBES2 error? The work-around given in the linked SO article seems complicated and uses reflection (which might be an issue in the GraalVM native images that we're building); any easier way that doesn't use reflection? I'd like to avoid extra dependencies, but if all else fails, I'll give BouncyCastle a try (if it's compatible with GraalVM).

EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo supports various PBES2 algorithms in Java versions as of 19, see here. For earlier versions or unsupported PBES2 algorithms, BouncyCastle is another option. In particular, the sample key posted can be imported with it, see the link in my last comment. I can't say for sure if BouncyCastle is compatible with GraalVM, so you'll have to try it out.

After doing some tests: With Java 21, I can successfully process keys generated using openssl genpkey ... -aes256 but not openssl genpkey ... --des-ede3-cbc (as expected based on earlier comments). With BouncyCastle, I can successfully process both. So, BC is the better option for processing arbitrary RSA keys, but I need to check whether I can make it work with GraalVM native images, and how much this increases the size of my CLI utility.
